# How to change the key for the latin alphabet key that I got asked to set up whole installing ubuntu 19.10?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

While installing ubuntu 19.10 I got asked to set a key to switch to a latin alphabet (I use an azerty french keyboard) and ubuntu recommended to use the right alt key, so I used it but now due to it, I can't write special character (like '@' or '[' for example). It is very annoying. I already got the advice to change the key in the keyboard shortcut setting but it isn't there, the "switch to next input" key is "Super + Space" but in the region and language setting it says that the "next source" shortcut is "Super+Space" AND "right alt"

Also disabling the english input source didn't get rid of the problem [You can see that it says that I got two shortcut and only the french keyboard input source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OFbwp.png)

[You can see here that in the keyboard shortcut setting only the Super + Space shortcut appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8eTk.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration` and change that setting to *No toggling*.
2. Run `gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options`